# cannot import name 'WKBWriter' from 'shapely.geos' when import google cloud ai platform

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-ai-platform

When I run this code on google colab.

`from google.cloud import aiplatform`

The following error occurred

`ImportError: cannot import name 'WKBWriter' from 'shapely.geos' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/shapely/geos.py)`

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

I was working fine on 2022/12/16, but today it is not working.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The bug is tracked in: https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/issues/1852

The workaround is to pin `shapely < 2.0.0`

```
pip install -U google-cloud-aiplatform "shapely<2"
```

Comment: do you know how I include this in a requirements.txt file?

Answer (score 0):

Running into a similiar issue. So far, I am able to tell that google.cloud actions will not run if I have shapley files installed. When I delete the shapley files on my computer I am able to run google.cloud methods

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).